# Manter rotas(URL) Angular2 válidas

Tags: angular

Estou iniciando os estudos a Angular 2 e encontrei uma possível limitação que não parece interessante para meu caso de uso de aplicação, pois ao que me parece não é possível reconstruir o estado da pagina através da URL da rota.

O exemplo que vou citar é o apresentando no ["CASE STUDY: TOUR OF HEROES", da documentação do angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html).

Neste [exemplo](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html) se você for na opção "Full screen" (para ter acesso a URL):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você vai perceber que a URL padrão será [`/dashboard`](http://run.plnkr.co/4zooE8uszcKxaev9/dashboard) e se você der F5, recarregar a pagina ou copiar a url para uma nova aba, a url não será valida, já se você copiar para seu browser e remover o `/dashboard` a pagina irá ser carregada corretamente.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma configuração ou alguma forma de manter essas rodas validas, para poderem ser copiadas e enviadas a outras pessoas?

Comment: Você já chegou a testar em algum trabalho seu? Ou somente através da demo deles? Pois eu criei um app básico para testes e comigo funcionou tudo perfeitamente, inclusive com parâmetros de URL. Se o problema persistir, talvez seja alguma configuração de servidor, como é o caso do Angular 1.x onde precisamos usar configurações no servidor para habilitar o uso de URL's amigáveis.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, Sim estou construindo uma aplicação real, e foi nela que reparei o problema. E fui observar se nos exemplos da documentação esse problema também existia, como havia o problema nos exemplos oficiais resolvi cita-los para ser mais fácil o entendimento e verificação do problema.

Comment: Que estranho.. Qual tipo de servidor você está usando?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, IIS Express para desenvolvimento. Mas suas rotas se manter validas ao aplicar refresh na pagina?

Comment: Sim, eu só testei por enquanto em Apache local e quando recarrego as páginas, independente da rota que eu esteja, ele recarrega normalmente. Até foi algo que me chamou atenção, pois no Angular 1.x é necessário muita configuração para habilitar essa função com URL amigável (sem `#`)

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, Muito estranho mesmo, pois o exemplo que citei da documentação esse comportamento não acontece. Você pode analisar superficial comparando ao exemplo da documentação se há alguma configuração das rotas do angular 2 diferente? Pois as minhas são um espelho das rotas da documentação.

Comment: Eu não tenho os meus arquivos no trabalho, chegando em casa eu dou uma olhada e te aviso, ok?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37282/discussion-between-fernando-and-celsomtrindade).